# Inverse Fourier transform of a function multiplied by $x$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution

Is there a way to write a general analytic expression for the inverse Fourier transform of a function multiplied by $x$?

I.e.

$$\mathcal F[g](x)=\int \text{d}t\, g(t)e^{-itx}$$

And we would like to find the inverse Fourier transform of

$$x\mathcal F[g](x)$$

i.e.
$$\int \text{d}x \mathcal F[g](x) x e^{irx}$$

Answer (score 1):

That's actually quite easy:
$$
x\mathcal{F}[g](x)
= x \int \mathrm{d}t \, g(t) e^{-itx} \, dt
= \int \mathrm{d}t \, g(t) x e^{-itx} \, dt
= \int \mathrm{d}t \, g(t) \left(i\frac{d}{dt} e^{-itx}\right) \, dt
\\
= i \int \mathrm{d}t \, g(t) \left(\frac{d}{dt} e^{-itx}\right) \, dt
= -i \int \mathrm{d}t \, g'(t) e^{-itx} \, dt
= -i \mathcal{F}[g'](x).
$$
Thus,
$$
x\mathcal{F}[g] = -i \mathcal{F}[g'].
$$